# "getLoginStatusUrl()" from the Facebook PHP sdk not working properly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, loginstatus

I am trying to determine whether a user is logged into Facebook or not. In the case that I am working with I would like to force him to log into my site even if he is logged into facebook already and has previously given me permissions.

```
$params = array(
  'ok_session' => 'http://localhost/fb_connect?ok_session=1',
  'no_user' => 'http://localhost/fb_connect?no_user=1',
  'no_session' => 'http://localhost/fb_connect?no_session=1',
);
$next_url = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params);
```

I was trying to use the code above (per the instructions on  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/) to determine what flow I need to guide my users through, but in the case when there is 'no_session' aka nobody is logged into Facebook, instead of getting the `'no_session'` url specified by the `$params`, I get the message `Application Error` on the facebook "check login status page"
Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, its broken:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295348980494364